# How to convert a number to the first divisible of another one in R

Tags: r, integer, division

I want to divide any number by `6` and still have an integer. so how can I make `R` convert a number to the closest divisible number.

For example `607` should be converted to `606` in this case.

Comment: Closest is 606.

Comment: `round(x / 6) * 6` for closest. Replace `round` with `floor` or `ceiling` to always go up or always go down.

Comment: `6*(607 %/% 6)`

Comment: @HubertL that's a (probably more efficient) way of doing using `floor`... will always go down, not to the closest.

Comment: `6*((609+6/2) %/% 6)` then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three approaches

```
foo_Gregor = function(N, n){
    return(round(N / n) * n)
}

foo_HubertL = function(N, n){
    return(n*((N+n/2) %/% n))
}

foo_db = function(N, n){
    t1 = N %% n
    if (t1 < n/2){
        return(N - t1)
    } else {
        return(N + n - t1)
    }
}    

var_db = sapply(1:10000, function(i) foo_db(N = i, n = 6))
var_Gregor = sapply(1:10000, function(i) foo_db(N = i, n = 6))
var_HubertL = sapply(1:10000, function(i) foo_db(N = i, n = 6))

identical(var_db, var_Gregor)
#[1] TRUE
identical(var_HubertL, var_Gregor)
#[1] TRUE
```

`foo_Gregor` is probably the best because of its simplicity and the ability to modify it with `floor` or `ceiling`